# AutoMapper: Map IList in model to IEnumerable in viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

Is it possible to map IList in Group to IEnumerable in GroupViewModel?

**Model**

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Permission> Permissions
    {
        get { return _permissoes ?? (_permissions = new List<Permission>()); }
        set { Permissoes.Clear(); _permissions = value; }
    }
}

public class Permission
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class GroupViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PermissionViewModel> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
var grp = new Group {Permissions = new List<Permission>{new Permission{Name="Permission 1"}, 
                                                       {new Permission{Name="Permission 2"}}}};

Mapper.CreateMap<Permission, PermissionViewModel>();

Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupViewModel>();


var result = Mapper.Map<GroupViewModel>(grp);
```